# Update Parent account in Account lookup on account contact relationship object

Tags: process-builder, account, contact, relationships, accountcontactrelation

As per my company business process we have all customer account as per Geo location. Parent account will be head office and branch offices are child accounts. 
Now, our requirement is all contact irrespective of child accounts should be visible under related contact list under parent account.
I can have related contact one by one via “New Account Contact Relationship” and select parent Account via lookup. But the problem is there are millions of contacts for customers. I tried with process builder but account lookup does not show on filed update on Account Contact Relationship.
Kindly advise how can I achieve it? Any help appreciated.

Comment: Is the account contact relationship object a custom object? What are the fields for the Account and Contact defined as - Master Detail or Lookup?

Comment: No it is not a customer object. It is a standard object.